# How to output a percent sign itself using boost.format?

Tags: c++, boost

How do you output a percent sign itself using Boost.Format?

i.e:

```
boost::format msg("5% complete"); // <- how to actually output the percent sign
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation for the [Boost Format library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/format/doc/format.html)? The answer to your question is in the [printf format specs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/format/doc/format.html#printf_directives) section.

Comment: Yes, I did try.  I could have dug it up, but when I did not find an answer on my first pass, I thought that such an easy question might be at the tip of someone's fingers, and perhaps useful for others in the future.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Simply escape it with another percent sign

```
boost::format msg("5%% complete");
```